# Is it possible in CMake to set properties of tests in a different directory scope than the one the test is defined in?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

For more structured test execution with "ctest -L" I want to set some labels on my unit tests. The labels I want to assign to a test are not yet clear at the time I declare the test. CMake seems to fail finding the test when not in the same directory scope, however with the same semantics it can modify properties of a target.

Here is my setup:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── a
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── a.cpp
    └── test_a.cpp
```

Where:
./CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(cmaketest LANGUAGES CXX)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(a)

# modify target and test properties
set_target_properties(a PROPERTIES LABELS "bla") # <-- works
set_tests_properties(mytest_a PROPERTIES LABELS "bla") # <-- fails
```

./a/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(a src/a.cpp)

# add tests for my
add_executable(test_a test/test_a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_a a)

add_test(NAME mytest_a COMMAND ./test_a)
```

CMake output is:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (set_tests_properties):
   set_tests_properties Can not find test to add properties to: mytest_a
   
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

using `set_tests_properties(mytest_a PROPERTIES LABELS "bla")` in a/CMakeLists.txt works, but not in the parent scope. Is this behavior intended? if so why? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google "`"set_property given TEST names that do not exist"`", you should should be able to find [(on discourse.cmake.org) Cannot set property of a test in a subdirectory](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cannot-set-property-of-a-test-in-a-subdirectory/4337?u=starball). The TL;DR is that test names are not required to be unique across directory scopes (currently not documented- at least- not in the docs for [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html)), so the behaviour you're observing is currently intended (both for [`set_tests_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_tests_properties.html) and [`set_property(TEST ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html)). [When asked, the maintainers were not aware of any workarounds](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cannot-set-property-of-a-test-in-a-subdirectory/4337/9?u=starball), aside from writing a wrapper function that adds the property, and calling the function in the same directory scope as where the test is defined by `add_test`. An issue ticket was created in relation to this behaviour: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22813.